# Show that $\phi(n) = 14$ is impossible

Tags: number-theory

I know this question may be a duplicate but I've seen a solution for this question which goes something along the lines of:

Recall that if $n = \prod_{i=1}^{r}p_i^{\alpha_{i}}$ then $\phi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}(p_i - 1)p_i^{\alpha_{i}-1}$. Suppose $\phi(n)= 14$. So $7|\phi(n)$. This implies that either $49|n$ (in which case $\phi(n) \geq \phi(49) = 42 > 14$ so this can’t happen) or $7|(p − 1)$ for one of the prime factors $p$ of $n$. The smallest prime with $7|(p−1)$ is $p = 29$, and if $29|n$ then again $\phi(n) \geq \phi(29) = 28 > 14$. So it is impossible to have $\phi(n) = 14$.

I'm confused on how $7|\phi(n)$ implies that $49|n$, would anyone be able to explain? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the negs btw, really helpful

Answer (score 2):

The statement is either $49 \mid n$ or $7 \mid p-1$. If $7 \mid p-1$ for some prime then we're done. If not then we must have that $7 \mid p^{a - 1}$, for some prime, which gives us that $p=7$. But as $a\ge 2$ we have that $7^2 \mid n$, as it appears in the prime factorization.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason this one really confused me. Still getting used to number theory